How Does the Depletion Region of a pn Junction Oppose Diffusion?
There's lots of questions about a p-n junction's depletion region on this site, but I don't think any of them are what I want to ask.
When I put together a n-type and a p-type semiconductor, the conduction band electrons in the n-type material migrate by diffusion to the p-type, find holes in the valence band there, and recombine. As a result, at the junction, a negatively charged region forms on the p-type side (from the migrated electrons) and a positively charged region forms on the n-type side (from the missing electrons).
Once the depletion region is formed, Wikipedia says "This creates an electric field that provides a force opposing the charge diffusion." But why should the electric field oppose diffusion rather than aiding it?

Let's assume no external bias for the moment. If I imagine a conduction band electron in the n-type material "neutral region" after the depletion region has formed, I expect that that electron feels a force repelling it from the negative region on the p-type side, but I also expect that it feels an attractive force from the positively charged region on the n-type side. And furthermore that positive charge is closer to any conduction band electrons remaining in the n-type region. So why, for example, doesn't the depletion region act as a kind of "slingshot", allowing electrons from the n-type region to accelerate toward the depletion region and then past the negative part and into the p-type "neutral area"?
In short, what makes the depletion region oppose diffusion?


But why should the electric field oppose diffusion rather than aiding it?

As shown in the diagram, the field points from the positive charge to the negative charge:

That means any holes diffusing from the left are pushed back to the left, and electrons diffusing from the right are pushed back to the right.
Why does the E field point from right to left? Because the positive space charge is on the right and the negative space charge is on the left.

I also expect that it feels an attractive force from the positively charged region on the n-type side. And furthermore that positive charge is closer to any conduction band electrons remaining in the n-type region.

Two things going on here.

The diagram is misleading where it shows "linear" grading of the mobile carrier concentration in the space charge region. The space charge region is effectively swept free of mobile charges, so the mobile carrier concentration is near 0 (or off scale if the scale is meant to be logarithmic). That means there are no "conduction band electrons remaining".

We derive this simplified view of the junction assuming the junction dimensions in the y and z directions (perpendicular to the x shown in the diagram) are very large compared to the length of the space charge region. Then we can use the result you should know from when you learned Gauss's law, that the field due to an "infinite" sheet of charge doesn't diminish as you get farther away from the sheet --- so the field a mobile carrier experiences doesn't depend on whether it's closer to the negative space charge region or the positive space charge region, it only depends on how much of each region is to its left or to its right. The field is always either 0 (in the neutral regions) or pointing right to left (in the space charge region).



I guess (2) is really the point. I was thinking of conduction band electrons in the area labeled "neutral region" in the diagram, but if I think of your infinite sheets point, then in fact the two sheets "cancel" their forces for these electrons. But I can't get away with a negligibly wide junction model forever: adding an external bias allegedly widens or narrows the junction. So how can I reconcile that?

Actually I think I've resolved my additional confusions. Thanks!
